# Jetty wrong encoding

Tags: character-encoding, jetty

I'm using maven and Jetty to run web applications. I've set the encoding of JSP, Tomcat and MySQL tables to `utf-8`. Also set `-Dorg.eclipse.jetty.URI.charset=utf-8`. But the data stored in the database still has the wrong encoding.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: More information required. Jetty doesn't write into a database table - your code does, so until you tell us how data gets from an HTTP request into a database table we cannot help you.